# React native - creating an APK

Tags: react-native, expo, apk

I want to create an APK from my react native application.
To do so, I use *expo*, being based on this [web page](https://dev.to/chinmaymhatre/how-to-generate-apk-using-react-native-expo-kae).

I created two apps (app A that is completely empty and app B that is full of code), because I want to figure out in which file inside APK my code is stored (this code that I wrote in the app B).
But the problem is that even when I will add a few thousand lines of code the size of APK will be still the same and basically everything is the same in both APKs.

Any ideas what might be wrong? In my opinion the APK of app B should be much bigger, but it doesn't.

Comment: Compiled JavaScript codes are minified when bundled inside the app. Most File Manager (Finder & Window Explorer) app round file size when shown in MB unit. It is hard to notice the difference.

Comment: Try to add heavy assets like high-resolution images, you will notice the difference easier.

Comment: Actually I did it, but I couldn't still see any changes.